# C# Cancel execution of a task with multiple tasks in it

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to cancel a task that has multiple tasks in it, for example:

```
 private async Task<bool> myTask0() {
       var val2 = await myTask2();
       var val3 = await myTask3();            
       return true;
    }
```

where:

```
private async Task<bool> myTask1() {
       //run some tasks in paralell
        var myParallel= arrayValues.Select(fileBEanListItem => manageSrcFilesDownload().ToList();
        return true;
    }

   private async Task<bool> myTask2() {
        return await myTask3();
    }
```

So I'd like to gave the option to cancel `myTask0` with all tasks in it - just abort it! Is there a solution:

I am trying:

```
 var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
 CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;

 await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
                await myTask0();
        },ct);
```

and when I need to close it, I use `ts.Cancel(true);` but no effect, tasks are running anyway.

Comment: I think cancelation tokens usually signal that from outside aborting is requested. But you have to handle that abort inside your routines. At least in the `BackGroundWorker` it is the case. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) is an example. May be it helps

Comment: You need to pass the token into your methods and then check it to end the execution.  Check out this post about it https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/

Comment: A cancellation token cannot force cancellation. You must inspect the token within your task from time to time and exit the task if cancellation is requested.

Answer (score 2):

[Cancellation is cooperative](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx). So, you should pass the `CancellationToken` down through your methods:

```
private async Task<bool> myTask0(CancellationToken token) {
   var val2 = await myTask2(token);
   var val3 = await myTask3(token);            
   return true;
}

private async Task<bool> myTask1(CancellationToken token) {
   //run some tasks in paralell
   var myParallel= arrayValues.Select(fileBEanListItem => manageSrcFilesDownload(token).ToList();
   return true;
}

private async Task<bool> myTask2(CancellationToken token) {
    return await myTask3(token);
}
```

And so on, until you either pass the token to APIs that can take it (e.g., file download), or until you have your own code that uses `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` or `CancellationToken.Register` to respond to cancellation.

On a side note, [`StartNew` is an anti-pattern](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). As I explain on my blog, you should use `Task.Run` instead. In particular, [the `CancellationToken` parameter (for both `StartNew` and `Run`) only cancels the *scheduling* of the delegate](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html); they won't *abort* your code. For proper cancellation support, you have to write code that responds to a `CancellationToken`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Stephen Cleary

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> In the Task classes, cancellation involves cooperation between the user delegate, which represents a cancelable operation and the code that requested the cancellation.  A successful cancellation involves the requesting code calling the CancellationTokenSource.Cancel method, and the user delegate terminating the operation in a timely manner.